# $n$ to the $n$th power has $n$ digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Determine all positive integers $n$ for which $n$ to the $n$th power has precisely $n$ digits.

I am having no idea how to approach this one.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Even without the clever hints in the answers, if you just try setting $n$ to each number $1$, $2$, $3$, etc. you may see a pattern develop. That's often a good way to start. (In this case, though, beware that the "pattern" from the first four or five numbers may be misleading--also look at some easy larger numbers, such as $10$ or $100$.)

Comment: 1,8,9 are the only solutions.....????

Comment: I think you may have figured it out now. Robert Israel's hint is a very good one concerning the possibility that any higher value of $n$ could exist.

Comment: Note that if $n\ge10$, then $n^n\ge10^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $x$ has $n$ digits if $10^{n-1} \le x < 10^n$.

Comment: so there is no natural number which satisfies this.

Comment: Am I right?????????????????????

Comment: No, there definitely are natural numbers with the property.

Comment: only n=1 is the solution.....

Comment: 1,8,9 are the only solutions.....

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $10^n$ has $n+1$ digits.

Answer (score 2):

There are exactly three solutions- 1,8,9. 10^n has exactly n+1 digits.